# Why are my objects in all layers?

Tags: objects, layers

I have the same objects in all 20 layers.
If I delete one of them, the objects in all twenty layers are deleted, not the single one.

I would like the have my object in the first layer only.
Any solutions?

Comment: This happens in Blender - usually when you import a model such as .obj etc.   The solution is to go to one of the layers, select the object and "Move" it to layer 1. (or any other)  It's been a year since I've encountered this but I'm fairly sure that will eliminate all the clones - think we've just doubled here @gandalf3, ha ha!

Comment: @PaulGonet Why did you delete your answer? I think it was quite useful.

Answer (score 4):

Try selecting the object and pressing **<kbd>M</kbd>** to move between layers. If all the layers are selected in the dialog which subsequently appears, press <kbd>1</kbd> (or click on the first layer in the dialog with <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd>) to move the object to just that layer.

Answer (score 0):

Hey go to Menu Properties (right)- Object Panel - Menu Relations - Layers. If all the squares are in dark gray, it means that your object is repeated in all layers, you should remove this cliking just in the layer that you are working on.